# PHP: Get age accurate to month but not day (from a date)

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, datetime

I would like to get the age (in years only) of a person from the date of birth provided (format: 1988-07-22).

I specifically want to calculate by accuracy of month, rather than day, in order to protect the specific birthday-day from other users (but still display the age accurate to whatever month their birthday is in)

So far I am getting the age in years as follows:

```
    $from = new DateTime($user['date_of_birth']);
    $to = new DateTime('today');
    $user['age'] = $from->diff($to)->y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
$from = new DateTime($user['date_of_birth']);
$to = new DateTime('today');
$age = $from->diff($to)->y . "years and " . $from->diff($to)->m . " months."
```

For a given date of birth (say, 1988-07-22), you will get "25 years and 11 months". For 1988-07-18 (today), you get "26 years and 0 months".